# How to create an object from a DLL file in c++ at runtime?

Tags: c++, class, object, dll

I have a DLL file which has a class called trial and it contains a function called test, I have another project in which I loaded the DLL using the loadlibrary function from the windows module, now I want to know how to create an object of type trial in the new project.

I tried defining the class as "class __declspec(dllexport) trial" but I don't know how to create an object in the main file now.

Trail.h is as follows:

```
class __declspec(dllexport) TRIALSHARED_EXPORT Trial
{
public:
    Trial();
    void test();
};
```

Trail.cpp is as follows:

```
extern "C"{
Trial::Trial(){
    cout<<"object is created"<<endl;
}
    void Trial:: test(){
    cout<<"dynamic thingy"<<endl;
}
}
```

The main function is as follows:

```
int main()
{
    HINSTANCE here=LoadLibrary(L"C:\\Users\\vinay\\Documents\\qt c++\\build-trial-Desktop_Qt_5_12_0_MinGW_64_bit-Debug\\debug\\trial.dll");
    if(!here){
        cout<<"could not load the lib"<<std::endl;
    }
    else{
        cout<<"library loaded"<<endl;
        typedef void(*FNPTR)();
        FNPTR fn=FNPTR(GetProcAddress(here,"Trial"));
        fn();
    }
}
```

Comment: You basically need the corresponding header file.

Comment: Did you consider load-time-binding? That means to not use `LoadLibrary`, but instead using the export library that can be created while the DLL is linked. The program shown with your `main` function would link with the stubs that are defined in the export library. With load-time-binding you still use the same approach with a DLL that implements the/some class(es).  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/load-time-dynamic-linking

Comment: @MaxLanghof do i need to include Trial.h in my main? for me to create an object of the type Trial?

Comment: @harper i am supposed to achieve the goal via run time linking only. is there a way i can achieve this in run time binding?

Comment: That's where the `Trial` class is defined. Without the header, you cannot tell the compiler what `Trial` looks like, so you can't use it in any meaningful way in your code (other than possibly an opaque handle). There is no reflection in C++ (yet), the compiled binary does not contain sufficient information to reconstruct a given type. See for yourself: https://godbolt.org/z/9Ctkxo

Comment: Please don't extend your question in comments. If you need to clarify some requirements like "run time linking only", this should be part of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can't use load-time binding you should use a pattern with a factory. The factory creates an instance of an object that implements an interface. The interface is a abstract class that can be used in the consumer.

Change your header file like this:

```
class ITrial
{
public:
    virtual void test() = 0;
};

class Trial : ITrial
{
public:
    Trial();
    virtual void test() override;
};

// declare a function name that can be easily found with GetProcAdress.
extern "C" TRIALSHARED_API ITrial* CreateTrial();
typedef ITrial* (*PFN_Factory)();
```

*Edit:* The class `ITrial` is the interface to the functionality. You define a contract between the implementation and the consumer of the DLL. Only members that are defined here can be accessed. The DLL defines a class that is inherited from the interface class as the implementing class. The implementing class can have any additional member as it needs. 
*Edit end.*

The header file must not include the `__declspec(dllexport)`. The macro `TRIALSHARED_EXPORT` should be defined using conditional compilation.

```
#ifdef TRIAL_EXPORTS // defined only in the exporting DLL project
#define TRIALSHARED_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define TRIALSHARED_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

Add to your Trial implementation:

```
ITrial* CreateTrial()
{
    return new Trial;
}
```

Change your main function:

```
int main()
{
    auto here=LoadLibrary(L"C:\\Users\\vinay\\Documents\\qt c++\\build-trial-Desktop_Qt_5_12_0_MinGW_64_bit-Debug\\debug\\trial.dll");
    if(!here) {
        cout<<"could not load the lib"<<std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    auto factory = reinterpret_cast<PFN_Factory>(GetProcAddress(here, "CreateTrial"));
    if (!factory) {
        cout<<"could not find factory"<<std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    auto pTrial = factory();
    if (!pTrial) {
        cout<<"factory failed"<<std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    pTrial->test();
    delete pTrial;
}
```

The error handling is a bit clumsy. Change it as you need.

Comment: OK, so you can export classes using the factory approach! But it's clumsy, messy, and prone to mis-use.

Comment: @Adrian it also allows backwards-compatibility of new versions and not having to re-compile everything that depends on the library when you extend it.

Comment: Thanks! i kinda used a similar approach and was able to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

There are numerous errors in your code and, ***more importantly***, in the approach you are taking.  First, you need to define `class Trial` as `__declspec(dllexport)` **when you build the DLL** but as `__declspec(dllimport)` **when you build the EXE**! This is conventionally done using pre-processor decisions, like so:

```
#ifdef _DLL // Assuming a Windows DLL build
#define IMPOREXP __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define IMPOREXP __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
class IMPOREXP Trial
{
public:
    Trial();
    void test();
};
```

Next - and critically - you can't use a class defined in a DLL unless you use implicit 'load-time binding'! The `LoadLibrary()` and `GetProcAddress()` functions can do *nothing* about exported/imported classes.

I can give more, if you think it will be useful: comment a question or 'accept', and I'll try to guide you through the process with further examples.

Comment: The `#idef _DLL` works only if the header file is not included in a consuming DLL. To make this conditional compile robust you need to check a define that's unique in the implementing DLL preprocessor defines.

Comment: @harper Re: '#ifdef _DLL` - Yes, my code sample was a 'conventional' example.